# How do I set up a Ginkgo test suite?

Tags: go, ginkgo

I have inherited a Go project that consists of a lot of common files, a library of sorts, two executables, and theoretically a test suite.  The test suite is being written after the fact.  But I dislike the only way I've found of setting up is rather unpalatable

I'm using Ginkgo, and this is my starting directory structure

- component1/component1.go
- component2/component2.go
- cmd1/cmd1.go
- cmd2/cmd2.go
- project_suite_test.go
- component1_test.go

Each cmd?.go file will be compiled into a separate executable.

What I would like is a multi-file test suite, usually one file per component.  Where do I put the files so that `go test` will find and run all of them, without leaving them here in the root of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `go test ./...` in the root and it will go into child folders and execute the tests:

```
component1/component1.go
component1/component1_test.go
component2/component2.go
component2/component2_test.go
cmd1/cmd1.go
cmd1/cmd1_test.go
cmd2/cmd2.go
cmd2/cmd2_test.go
```

Answer (score 2):

`ginkgo init` and `ginkgo bootstrap` will set up your tests. `ginkgo -r` will run all your tests recursively.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**
Ginkgo command will only work if you have actually bootstrap your project via ginkgo.

**Options:**
To use that you have to go to your test dir in terminal and run

`ginkgo init` : To Initialise project:

`ginkgo bootstrap` : This will generate new file with test suite config

`ginkgo` or `ginkgo test` : this will now be able to run tests based on your new generated file because that's what it is trying to search.

**Alternatively:**

If you like to keep your tests in a sub-folder, say test, then running

```
go test ./...
```

will attempt to run tests in every folder, even those that do not contain any test, thus having a ? in the subsequent report for non-test folders.

Running

```
go test ./.../test
```

instead will target only your test folders, thus having a clean report focused on your tests folders only.

you can alternatively use `'go run $(ls *.go)'` to run all the files in a given folder.
Notice you have regular expression within () braces.

In-case you want to run test in different path update path as per your desired dir in the regular expression